# How to integrate outlook 2013 calendar?

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm working in an organization where we have our own exchange server. I'm developing a performance system to our employees using erpal.

I need an integration between exchange and Drupal that allows the employees to use their outlook calendar and tasks as same as erpal calendar and task (I mean the synchronization).

I found some ways doing it by using import and export but I think these ways are for Individual person. I need an automatic synchronization for all employees who have an email in our exchange server and can login to the system.

Is there any setting or module I have do? Or any steps link I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look for the following modules:

- [Click to Schedule](https://www.drupal.org/project/click_to_schedule)

  > It has sync capabilities for Outlook, Google calendar or iCal for Mac. Meetings are automatically confirmed, added to your Outlook, Google Calendar, or iCal and confirmation emails are sent to both parties.
- [CiviCRM activities iCalendar feed](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_activity_ical)

  > Users can access an iCal feed of their upcoming (future) Activities, suitable for subscription via Google Calendar, Microsoft Outlook, and/or similar software.

Comment: hi kenorb
first of all, thank you for your response.
I tried to use -click to schedule but it looks there is a limitation for employees number. + each employee should has an account in timetrade !!

currently am trying the civicrm activities.